# Block YouTube from Fortinet firewall

Tags: firewall

My company have Fortinet firewall. we need to block YouTube from entire network. we already make firewall rule for block YouTube and that rule not applying only for Google chrome. YouTube Still working on Google Chrome browser. i think this is because of QUCK protocol. so i create another rule for block QUCK protocol. but still YouTube working. when i clean cache memory youtube not working. most of the users bringing there laptops to home and watching youtube from there personol connections. when they come again to company network. again youtube working. please support me to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the logs to see what addresses and protocols are actually being used? Once you discover that, you should be able to block it.

Comment: how i can do that? can you support me?

Comment: i checked with wire-shark. when i block QUCK protocol from chrome, all the youtube traffic going on TCP

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use application control to block youtube.

> Go to security profiles click on application control -> Create new (give name youtube block) -> block category video/audio -> In application overrides add signature Youtube.

Go to your internet policy and apply this app control to it. 
It will block your Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to configure "URL Filtering".

> You can allow or block access to specific URLs by adding them to the
>   Static URL Filter list.

- [Fortinet](http://help.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/54/Content/FortiOS/fortigate-security-profiles-54/Web_Filter/Static%20URL%20Filter.htm)

Comment: Yes i did it. but nothing happening. still can access youtube on google chrome. this probmel only for youtube with google chrome.

Comment: This is sometimes called "Web Filter".  While you can certainly build a custom solution in Cisco IOS for example, I'd call Fortinet support.  Maybe upgrade code?  Their system should deliver this capability point& click style.

Answer (score 0):

If you block UDP port 80 and 443 that should block QUCK.
Of course you need have in place as well URL filter for youtube over TCP.